# extracting whole line in awk if condition using cut -d

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I want to get the value of the 11th column in my tab delimited file.
This return value is multiple values concetenated using : as seperator.

```
example result from cat myFile | cut -d':'    :
.:7:.:2:100:.
```

I now want to split this file on the : seperator and retrieve the second value.
This can be done with `cut -d':' -f2`

my question:
How can I make a statement which returns all lines in my file which have value 5 or more in the second part of the 11th column?

input file (2 lines):

```
chr1    4396745 bnd_549 a   a[chr9:136249370[   100 PASS    SVTYPE=BND;MATEID=bnd_550;EVENT=transl_inter_1022;GENE=;    GT:AD:DP:SS:SSC:BQ  .:.:.:.:.:. .:7:.:2:100:.
chr1    6315381 bnd_551 c   ]chr9:68720182]c    100 PASS    SVTYPE=BND;MATEID=bnd_552;EVENT=transl_inter_9346;GENE=;    GT:AD:DP:SS:SSC:BQ  .:.:.:.:.:. .:3:.:2:100:.
```

expected output:

```
chr1    4396745 bnd_549 a   a[chr9:136249370[   100 PASS    SVTYPE=BND;MATEID=bnd_550;EVENT=transl_inter_1022;GENE=;    GT:AD:DP:SS:SSC:BQ  .:.:.:.:.:. .:7:.:2:100:.
```

output with (awk -F: '$11>=5' example.sorted.vcf):
no output

Comment: Please give a complete example how your file looks (i.e. one row that matches and one which doesn't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work (though untested, please provide input and expected output):

```
awk '{split($11,ary,/:/); if(ary[2]>=5) print}' myFile
```

Comment: Isn't the output supposed to be the whole line?  So just `print` or `print $0` instead of `print ary[2]`?  And `>=` rather than `>`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, the original question mentioned about getting the second value, so I was not sure. Have updated the answer to reflect the changes. Thanks for catching the `>=`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use whitespace or colon as the field separator:

```
awk -F ':|[[:blank:]]+' '$23 > 5' filename
```